# iOS custom grid view for iPad App to show downloaded images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

[image: I want to make this type of view in my app.]

add an object of type collection view then make a proper connection through collection inspector.

in .h file

```
IBOutlet UICollectionView   *myCollection;
```

in viewdidload

```
 myCollection.delegate = self;
myCollection.dataSource = self;
```

and the data source / delegate  methods are :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
return 15;
}

 // The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout: (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *  )indexPath
{
return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

getting this error

```
could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CellID -   must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a   storyboard'
```

what should i do now… please help me to resolve it..

Comment: Did you try anything and have a problem?

Comment: Did you set as like [collectionView registerClass:[HACollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];?

Comment: @Natarajan thanks for bearing me … but please tell me where do set it

Comment: @Natarajan yes i did it… thanks … just add this line in viewdidload [myCollection registerClass:[DetailInvoicing2 class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UICollectionView` to show grid view in iOS.

For Example:

In HAViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HACollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@end

@interface HAViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@end
```

in HAViewController.m

```
#import "HAViewController.h"    

@implementation HACollectionCell


@end

@implementation HAViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    UICollectionView * collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width) collectionViewLayout:layout];

    collectionView.delegate = self;

    collectionView.dataSource = self;

    [collectionView registerClass:[HACollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];

    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];

    collectionView = nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: @ interface HACollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell @ end
 …. will you please tell me what it means here. how and why to include it

Comment: It will be used to register your custom collection cell to UICollectionView. Ex : [collectionView registerClass:[HACollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];

Comment: You can do your more customization in HACollectionCell. It will be same as like UITableView custom cell.

Comment: please check my edited question… i have tried but getting some exceptions… :(